# Reuse controller or create a configurable directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my site I have a case where I show a simple order which I can add/remove items to and pay to close the order.In other case , I just want to show the order without the option to modify it.

What is the best way to do this regarding to reuse the view ?
Should I create a directive which I can configure to not show update actions 
or should I create 2 templates (one for each scenario) which bound to the
same controller but each template use only the methods it needs from the controller?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may conditionally close GUI items when your order view is in readonly mode, for example:

```
<button ng-if="!readonly">Add new item</button>
```

Of course your controller should have

```
$scope.readonly=true;
```

when you are going to display the view without ability to modify it.

Comment: Do you mean I should use a directive?

Comment: No, just control your GUI elements visibility in your view